# Make an bootable USB drive from android terminal

Tags: boot, usb, android

I am trying to make my USB bootable, which already have files in it (the [ntpassword](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) utility to activate admin user). 
The problem is I dont have another PC to execute the `X:syslinux.exe -ma X:` command (mentioned in the docs to make the USB bootable).
However I have an android box (which is linux?), so my question, how (using the android terminal) can I make my USB bootable using linux command? anything similar to the command above.